# BeautifulSoup .previous_sibiling returns None

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

Here's the sample HTML

```
<tr id="gift1" class="gift"><td>
Vegetable Basket
</td><td>
This vegetable basket is the perfect gift for your health conscious (or overweight) friends!
<span class="excitingNote">Now with super-colorful bell peppers!</span>
</td><td>
$15.00
</td><td>
<img src="../img/gifts/img1.jpg">
</td></tr>
```

And I'm trying to parse the price of an object represented by its image url.

```
html = getHTML("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(bsObj.find("img", {"src":"../img/gifts/img1.jpg"}).parent.previous_sibiling)
```

`bsObj.find("img", {"src":"../img/gifts/img1.jpg"}).parent` returns:

```
<td>
<img src="../img/gifts/img1.jpg">
</td>
```

But `bsObj.find("img", {"src":"../img/gifts/img1.jpg"}).parent.previous_sibiling` always returns **None**.

Shouldn't that be returning `<td>` tag for the price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have a typo - `previous_sibiling` vs `previous_sibling`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> data = """<tr id="gift1" class="gift"><td>
... Vegetable Basket
... </td><td>
... This vegetable basket is the perfect gift for your health conscious (or overweight) friends!
... <span class="excitingNote">Now with super-colorful bell peppers!</span>
... </td><td>
... $15.00
... </td><td>
... <img src="../img/gifts/img1.jpg">
... </td></tr>"""
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
>>> 
>>> image_url = "../img/gifts/img1.jpg"
>>> 
>>> image = soup.find("img", src=image_url)
>>> price = image.parent.previous_sibling.get_text(strip=True)
>>> print(price)
$15.00
```

Another option would be to use [`find_previous()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-previous-and-find-previous) to find a text node that starts with `$`:

```
>>> price = image.find_previous(text=lambda text: text and text.strip().startswith("$")).strip()
>>> print(price)
$15.00
```

Comment: ohh it's the typo. it did return None. so I never thought about the typos. ty